# Elements disappearing from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having some troubles with this code:

```
ArrayList<Shop> listShops = new ArrayList<Shop>();
Shop currShop = new Shop();

String query = "SELECT * FROM Shop WHERE... ";

try {
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()) {
        currShop.setName(rs.getString(1));
        currShop.setDescription(rs.getString(2));
        System.out.println(listShops.add(currShop));
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("List size: "+listShop.getSize());
for(Shop s: listShop) {
    System.out.println(s.getName());
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
true 
[...]
List size: 78
[78 empty strings]
```

And I'm not understanding why it is giving me those empty lines. I'm 100% sure that currShop works fine because I printed `currShop.getName()` and `currShop.getDescription()` (in the rs.next() while) and they both work. It also gives me "true" booleans indicating a successful insert into the ArrayList, so why doesn't it print anything?

Comment: please show me the steName method in the Shop class....

Comment: Shop currShop = new Shop(); this is the same for every shop and is being overridden, put it inside while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a new `Shop` object every time inside the while loop:

```
while(rs.next()) {
    Shop currShop = new Shop();
    currShop.setName(rs.getString(1));
    currShop.setDescription(rs.getString(2));
    System.out.println(listShops.add(currShop));
}
```

Otherwise, you are just adding a single `Shop` instance many times to the list, overwriting the name and description on each iteration.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I thought that the ArrayList would have automatically generated an object inside itself with the same characteristics of the one passed as argument, my bad! Sorry for having disturbed you guys.

Comment: No problem. You can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark after you have confirmed it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Wim is right you must create a new Object inside the loop. Otherwise there is no point in overwriting the same old object again and again.

By using inside your while loop

`Shop currShop = new Shop();`

will be created a new instance everytime and the `listShops.add(currShop)` will have add new item on each insert.

This kind of mistake happens in the beginning, no worries keep learning !